# Yii and Google Api PHP Client

Tags: php, yii, google-api-php-client

I need to add [Google Api PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to my Yii 1.1 project.
I'm new in Yii, but I have already used this library.
How can I import this (whithout composer) ?

I'll tried to put google-api-php-client in vendor folder and add this line

```
Yii::import('application.vendor.*');
require_once('google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php');
```

but when I use:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
```

I got this error:

```
include(Google_Config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the correct path is

```
Yii::import('application.vendor.*');
require_once('google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the `__DIR__` magic constant. It allows you to work with files using the current file as the base location.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Most likely this is what you are running into.